# How to fix Warning during anchor build: unused variable: `ctx`

Tags: anchor, rust

```
warning: unused variable: `ctx`
 --> programs/calculator-dapp/src/lib.rs:9:23
  |
9 |     pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
  |                       ^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_ctx`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution is in the warning message:

> prefix it with an underscore: _ctx

For example:

```
    pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
       ...
    }
```

Generally, you'll use the context to access the accounts for your instructions, but the example above should get rid of the warning.